# Jquery autocomplete value not being passed to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an input with Jquery autocomplete. While I am able to display the desired values, the form does not pass it back to code.  Is there anything else that I need to do? Form passes blank.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = ['Software Engineer', 'Project manager'];
  $("#id_j_title").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<body>


  <form id="search-form" method="POST" action=".">
    <p>
      <label for="id_j_title">Enter a keyword for the job title for the new application:</label>
      <input id="id_j_title" maxlength="11" name="j_title" type="text" />
    </p>
    And

    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
    <button>Back</button>
  </form>


</body>
```

Comment: When I type in `Soft` it shows the term Software Engineer and when I click it it populates the form. What do you want.

Comment: But when I submit the form the value is not being passed to view. I am using djnago.

Comment: If you remove the autocomplete javascript does it work? So just manual text entry.

Comment: Nope.  Thanks. I was just hung on Jquery as this is something new I am using :)    Thanks a ton.

Comment: So yeah, if you just put text in there and click submit and nothing comes through on the other end then you have another problem on your hands with the form. At a glance after you submit you should have something in your Form or Post object for whatever server side language you are using that has a `j_title` in it with what you put in. If it's not there and you can't figure it out I'd make another question.

Comment: Found the fault in my code. So there is nothing to accept or show my gratitude to you here other than thanks? Thanks one more time.